# Factorizing a header menu in Django template

Tags: django, navigation, django-views, django-templates

I'm building a website using django with a header on top of every page, which basically is a menu with a few links, constant throughout the pages.

However, depending on the page you're on I'd like to highlight the corresponding link on the menu by adding the class "active". To do so, I am currently doing as follow: each page has a full menu block that integrates within a general layout, which does NOT contain the menu. For exemple, page2 would look like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block menu %}
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:index' %}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:page1' %}">page1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="{% url 'myapp:page2' %}">page2</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:page3' %}">page3</a></li>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that, beside from that solution being not so pretty, every time I want to add a link to the header menu I have to modify each and every page I have. Since this is far from optimal, I was wondering if any of you would know about a better way of doing so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a "page" object at every view, you could compare a navigation item's slug to the object's slug

**navigation.html**

```
<ul>
    {% for page in navigation %}
        <li{% ifequal object.slug page.slug %} class="active"{% endifequal %}>
            <a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**base.html**

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        {% include "navigation.html" %}
        {% block content %}
            Welcome Earthling.
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ object }}
{% endblock %}
```

Where navigation is perhaps a `context_processor` variable holding all the pages, and object is the current `PageDetailView` object variable

**Disclaimer**

There are many solutions for your problem as noted by Paulo. Of course *this* solution assumes that every view holds a page object, a concept usually implemented by a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). If you have views that do not derive from the Page app you would have to inject page pretenders within the navigation (atleast holding a `get_absolute_url` and `title` attribute).

This might be a very nice learning experience, but you'll probably save loads time installing  `feinCMS` or `django-cms` which both define an `ApplicationContent` principle also.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I understand well though this requires to pass a `navigation` variable containing all the pages each time I call a view? I guess I can store it in one place in the controller so it can be easily modified.

Comment: Usually you use a [context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to pass a variable to all of your views

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom templatetag:

```
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch, resolve

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def active(request, view_name):
    url = resolve(request.path)
    if url.view_name == view_name:
        return 'active'
    try:
        uri = reverse(view_name)
    except NoReverseMatch:
        uri = view_name
    if request.path.startswith(uri):
        return 'active'
    return ''
```

And use it in the template to recognize which page is loaded by URL

```
<li class="{% active request 'car_edit' %}"><a href="{% url 'car_edit' car.pk %}">Edit</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `include` tag and pass it a value which is the current page.

For example, this may be a separate file for declaring the menu template only:

## menu.html

```
{% if active = "a" %}
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:index' %}">Home</a></li>
{% if active = "b" %}
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:page1' %}">page1</a></li>
{% if active = "c" %}
<li class="active"><a href="{% url 'myapp:page2' %}">page2</a></li>
{% if active = "d" %}
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:page3' %}">page3</a></li>
```

And call this from within your template like this:

```
{% include 'path/to/menu.html' with active="b"%} # or a or c or d.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This isn't a very DRY approach, it could be an option in some rare cases though

Comment: Why it is not dry? He says it bother him to repeat the menu in every page. With this way you declare the menu in just one template. That's the definition of DRY! Don't repeat the menu everywhere. If you need to do some modifications you just only have to change the menu template. It has worked for me.

Comment: Yea but you still have a lot of if clauses within that template, instead of dynamically checking the value of active

Comment: About the lot of `if`s you're right, but, I can use your solution inside mine, passing just the `navigation` list and it would be very simple, pretty, refactored and dry. I just came with a fast solution I have used before with menus. The code is ugly indeed, but might be prettified easily. Still I prefer this than repeating the menu in every template, but is just me.

Comment: In my example you don't need the menu to be in every template either, just `base.html` or `navigation.html` or whatever you name it, as the `PageDetailView` object variable will be available globally within the template scope.

Comment: Yes, but now you're talking about adding a variable to a `context_processor`. It's a very nice solution, but personally I prefer treating this as __calling a method__ which is the template for my menu with an argument that is what I want to highlight. Still, I'm glad of this, there are different approaches for a solution and is good to see an answer with alternatives :)

Comment: Did you mean to write a serie of `<li{% if active = "c" %} class="active"{% endif %}>`? Seems a little less dynamic than the other solutions but it does give more arbitrary control over what is happening which can be a good thing, thank you very much !

Comment: My solution was to write a single template and store there all the logic for rendering the menus. This template would receive a parameter which you would use to now which menu is to mark as active. And you call this template from wherever you need to include the menu with the proper parameter. You replace the menu writing in every template for just an `include` tag.